# Can Bison verify scope as well as syntax?

Tags: compiler-construction, bison, yacc, lex, parser-generator

I am using  Lex/Bison to create a simple scripting language which translates into C. A trans-compiler.

I know Bison can verify syntax, but what about scoping? Can it verify the an identifier that is being used was declared before? Does that have to be done manually? And if so, at which step?

*E.g. This is syntax-wise correct. **But is should not compile** because message is in the wrong scope. In addition, message2 was never declared.*

```
String s1
if (s1=='knock on door')
   String message1='Hello';

print message1;
print message2;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsers (however produced) typically cannot check scoping rules.

To do scope checking in general, in general you have to build the entire AST and then verify the identifiers are well-scoped.    For languages which have static scoping with scopes introduced *before* variable use, you might be able to do this only the fly in rules.  For languages with namespaces, the namespace declaration might occur anywhere, and you can't do it without collecting that namespace and thus the entire program.    (The namespace declaration might not even be in the same file as the use; now you have parse an entirely different file).

As a consequence, the usual way scope checking is done is after parsing, over the program tree.   Normally if you are going to do anything beyond parsing, you need the tree, and the full symbol table anyway, so this isn't really much of an annoyance.

Some early compilers didn't have the luxury of holding the entire tree in memory.  Either they had languages with scope declarations before use, or they were implemented in multiple passes.

Comment: In some languages you cannot defer the scoping until you have an AST, because the parser cannot work without looking up that information. What is this:

    X(Y); /* C or C++ */

Is that a function call? Y being passed to X?  Or is it a declaration that Y is of type X?

You must check that X is declared to simply decide what kind of grammar symbol it is: type name, or a primary expression (function or variable).

Comment: @Kaz: This is a folk theorem pushed by the people that can't design parsers that handle ambiguities well.  The point of *syntax* is that you don't have to decide while parsing; if it might be several different things, just parse it as possibly being several different things. You can build the symbol table later, and then choose which subparse is acceptable.  Our C and C++ front ends (http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CppFrontEnd.html) work exactly this way, and they work just fine; they've been used to process millions of lines C and C++ code.

Comment: Hmm, in languages where you can easily tell (based on prior parts of the parse tree), it seems much more natural to me to pick that up in the parser while builing the AST, than to have to invent a magic type_or_variable symbol and then have to determine which it is when the whole AST is built.  It comes down to how you define "parsing" and what's easier to implement; but from my point of view you're moving part of the parser's job somewhere else just to avoid tying the scanner to the partially-built AST.

Comment: @Edmund:  Software Engineering is about building software effectively. A key method is make sure that respnsiblitiy for a task is packaged in one place and its structure hidden from other mechanisms (Parnas).  By tangling parsing and symbol table construction, you get a pretty ugly piece of machinery you have to implement and maintain by hand.  By isolating parsing and symbol table construction, it becomes a LOT easier to do so.  In the case of C++, this is pretty important, because symbol table lookups in C++ really are digustingly hard to do (see Keonig lookup)....

Comment: @Ira, I agree.  But part of the job of parsing is to determine the role (in broad terms) of every symbol.  By deferring that decision to a later stage, you've moved part of the parser's responsibility somewhere else.  I realise C++ is one of the trickiest commonly-used languages to parse so I can trust you've done the right thing in its case; I'm just saying that neither approach is 100% clean and so you need to think about the tradeoffs of each.

Comment: @Edmund: Parsing in the narrow technical sense is only syntax recognition.  As a practical matter, to process a real language, we need to parse it, build a tree, build symbol tables, type check it, compute control and data flow analyses, and compute any other useful generic facts.  I call that collectively a "front end", and use the term "parse" to mean that (plus build an AST, which we do by writing nothing at all; the parser knows what to do directly from the grammar).  We think we've made a very good set of tradeoffs, based on our success.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. There is actually a third phase called Semantic Analysis. The steps:

1. Lex  (get tokens)
2. Parse  (make sure token used in correct context)
3. Semantic Analysis  (type checking/scoping)

Semantic Analysis analyzes the parse tree that is created in Step 2.

Answer (score 0):

Bison does not handle identifier scoping and lookup. That functionality is up to you to provide in rule actions.

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle it in Bison without going through another pass after you obtain AST (abstract syntax tree) is,

- Create a data structure called "symbol table" that supports nested-scope, basically it is a tree of hashtables where each time you `pop_scope()` and `push_scope()` to a new scope, you switch to a new sibling node of scope with dead scopes information still saved.
- At your Bison rules where you create a new scope (so in your example, the `if` statement), use Bison [midrule action feature](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Using-Mid_002dRule-Actions.html#Using-Mid_002dRule-Actions) to invoke `push_scope()` at "entrance token" (`if` statement, `{` block begin, etc.). And invoke `pop_scope()` at the main action body.

Put in a concrete way, in your language, your original rule may look like:

```
selection-statement: _IF '(' expression ')' statement {
  /* main action */
}
```

With midrule action, you can insert an action for _IF, and pop, push scopes at corresponding spot directly in Bison, and it becomes:

```
selection-statement: _IF { push_scope(); } '(' expression ')' statement {
  /* main action */
  pop_scope();
}
```

So in your example, at the time symbol `message1` is defined, `push_scope()` is already being called at the point where parser encounters the `_IF` token when Bison is reducing this rule. And then when you try to read `message1` out side of its scope, your symbol table interface should return some error and you should be able to throw error message at Bison using `yyerror()`.

P.S. When you insert a midrule action, you should shift the reference numbers (e.g., `$0`, `$1`) for expressions. For a complex rule with midrule actions, this soon gets really messy and hard to read. A useful trick is using Bison [named references](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Actions.html) to avoid mistakenly using wrong reference names.